# Show buttons to latest record fetched from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on Job delivery system. seller can deliver job to the buyer and then the buyer can accept or request revision. if the seller delivered the job the buyer have two buttons Accept and Request Revision but if the deliver the job again I want to show the action buttons to the latest delivery instead of all the deliveries.

**I want to show all the deliveries but I want to show action buttons to the latest delivery.**

How can I do this?

```
<?php

    require_once('includes/initialize.php');

    $deliveries = get_job_deliveries($_GET['job']);

    while ($delivery = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deliveries)) {

?>

<h3 class="font-16 font-600 m-0 mb-3">
    <a class="text-primary" href="profile?user=<?php echo h($seller_name); ?>"><?php echo h($seller_name); ?></a> sent your delivery.
</h3>

<h5 class="font-14 font-600 m-0 mb-3">Are you pleased with the delivery and ready to approve it?</h5>

<button class="btn btn-primary w-md waves-effect waves-light mb-2 mr-3" id="review_seller_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>">Accept & Review Job</button>

<button class="btn btn-light w-md waves-effect waves-light mb-2" id="request_revision_<?php echo $delivery['id']; ?>">Request Revision</button>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: does your job delivery have a date? (im assuming it does) sort it using date descending and just limit it to 1. then you get the latest

Comment: I have, I want to show all the deliveries but only show action buttons to the latest delivery.

Comment: If I try like you are saying, I will only display latest delivery.

Comment: just simply fetch all the rows by date descending, and a simple if statement in the while block